# What are the ways in which I could store large amounts of data on the client browser?

Tags: html, validation, local-storage

I need to perform some validations on a form, which is going to be used repeatedly by multiple clients, against some data from my database. However, this validation needs to be very quick, and multiple clients are expected to be using the application simultaneously.

So I decided to get all the data in the form of JSON and store it on the client browser. All subsequent entries in the form will be validated against the data stored locally in the browser.

What are the ways in which I can store large amounts of data in the browser? I looked up HTML5's `localStorage`, which seems like a good choice. Are there any caveats with `localStorage`? What are the alternatives?

Comment: How large are we talking? I believe there are limits on storage capacity for localStorage.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes. 5 MB is what I found out. I think that's adequate.